# Which number to pluralise

Tags: grammatical-number, fractions

Do you say 'eights-and-a-half' or 'eight-and-a-halfs' when asking whether a person has that size in shoes or stockings?

Comment: Don't bother with a plural. _Do you have those in 8½?_ Dual clothing, like gloves, glasses, stockings, and trousers, is not really plural, and its size doesn't need to be plural, either.

Comment: Yep, it's "eight-and-a-half".

Comment: Also possible: "Do you have that [implied: item/pair] in an eight-and-a-half?"

Comment: You could say "Do you have eight-and-a-halfs?" ... but I think the suggestions above are ones you're more likely to hear in the wild.

Comment: And if I were working at the store, I would use "eight-and-a-halfs" when refering to multiple items/pairs, recognizing that it is a colloquial and probably incorrect time-saver for "items/pairs in size eight-and-a-half".

Comment: Another option is "Do you have any size eight and a half?".  // @MathieuK. - Why don't you put this in an answer?

Comment: There are two very different solutions there but never “'eights-and-a-half”… 

“Do you have any eight-and-a-halfs?”

“Do you have that style in an eight-and a-half?”